# sending eth to a specific address

Tags: solidity, ether, payable

i want to develop a contract where. when the function Optimizer is called it will send a specific amount of eth to a specific wallet address, problem is the wallet address is not receiving the amount when i call the optimizer function.

Code

```
  pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

contract AB {

   address payable  b= payable(0x9997aBff396d699FBFCEcbC17d69Bbe9343bD13e);

function Optimizer( )public  payable{

        msg.value==1000000000000000000 wei;

        require(msg.value==1000000000000000000 wei);


      b.transfer(msg.value);

    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should transfer the eth. Try:

```
b.transfer(msg.value)
```

You can learn more about it [here](https://solidity-by-example.org/sending-ether/).

Comment: if i do so  b.transfer(msg.value) the error shows :"send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable

Comment: Could you try: `payable(b).transfer(msg.value)`

Comment: no error but not transferring 1 eth/bnb

Comment: It would transfer `msg.value` eth which is the amount of eth you send when calling the function.

Comment: so i am using 1.4 eth, it should send the amount but it is not, also tried with 18 zero

Comment: Could you add `require(msg.value == 1.4 ether)` into the function just before transfer to make sure that `msg.value` is 1.4 eth?

Comment: using metamask, error shows Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
"code": -32000,
"message": "execution reverted"

Comment: Seems like you're not sending 1.4 eth, can you share the code? how are you calling the contracts function?

Comment: i have edited the code. plz look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140723/discussion-between-stofu-and-trizin).

Comment: could you check the inbox?